# SQL/JPA want to select data for a list of ids filtering by a specific timestamp range for each id

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table with some data, there are record id, userIds, timestamp and data columns. Receive from the client a list of userIds, initially, I just had to fetch data by the same timestamp range for all useIds, just using `userId IN (list)`. However, now I'm required to get data by different timestamp ranges for each userId, let's say userID 1 needs data from 1643580000000 to 1646431200000 and userId 2 from 1626418800000 to 1647500400000 (utcTimestamp in mills).

Most probably I'll receive a list of [userId, startTime, endTime], so, I was considering to loop the main query for each userId with its respective timestamp range (I've seen it's a bad idea due to performance, but if I have to, I have to), but I also found out about cursors (not much experience here).

I wanted to know if it's possible to get what I want without loops or cursors, and if not, best way with each one.

Thanks in advance!

Notes: using MariaDB. SQL query will be used as nativeQuery in a Java service repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a query laike this.

Of course you have to add for every user his own time range

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (userID = 1 AND `timestamp` BETWEEN 1643580000000 AND  1646431200000) 
OR (userId = 2 AND `timestamp`BETWEEN 1626418800000 AND 1647500400000)
```

If you have a lot of rows and not that many id to process, you can do it with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (userID = 1 AND `timestamp` BETWEEN 1643580000000 AND  1646431200000) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (userId = 2 AND `timestamp`BETWEEN 1626418800000 AND 1647500400000)
```

Here also you need to add for every id another UNION

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting approach, the only issue with my needs is that I don't know before hand the number of userIds, userIds list size is variable, and it can be large, let's say 1000 userIds. Also, the query will be executed from java, I might need to build the string, and as [userIds,start,end] grows, so will the string and query. I will keep in mind the approach though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you said in your question you want for every user their own dates, so i see no other option than my code. if you ave 1000 ids and 2000 timestamps, you must use a loop over all ids and make one of the solutions, but for 100 i think only solution number 1 will be used. MAKe a combine Index on userid and timestamp, so that the query will be runing

Comment: I see, I'll try it out and update when I get something running. Thanks a lot!

Comment: UPDATE: I'll mark this answer as the solution since my implementation is based on your advise to solve the issue. In the end I decided to create a temp table with the userIds and startTime, endTime for each userId, since I get the userIds and time  ranges from the client in a Java REST API (table is dropped when session ends), then I joined that temp table with the one with the data and added a `WHEN record_timestamp BETWEEN temp_table.start AND temp_table.end` to filter data for each specific range per userId, and it worked, without needing loops. Response under .7 s with under 100 ids.